# Must_not in bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Usecase : I want to delete all the documents that are not having certain id's .

Mappings:

```
"bookList": {
                  "properties": {
                     "bookname": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "bookId": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
}
```

The content will be like this in each document : Some have inner lists let it be `DOC1` :

```
"bookList": [
                  {
                     "bookname": "HITLER",
                     "bookId": 3163
                   },
                   {
                       "bookname": "MARTIAN", 
                       "bookId": 1210
                   }
                   ]
```

And some only one list like this Let it be `DOC2`

```
"bookList": [
                  {
                     "bookname": "WASHINGTON",
                     "bookId": 3163
                   }
                   ]
```

And another document DOC3:

```
 "bookList": [
                      {
                         "bookname": "SHELDON",
                         "bookId": 3163
                       },
                       {
                           "bookname": "MARVELS", 
                           "bookId": 1219
                       }
                       ]
```

I am using delete_by_query plugin in ES 2.4.0 to delete the documents that are NOT having `bookId : 3163` using MUST_NOT in bool query . For inner lists documents(i.e.DOC1 & DOC3) it is not deleting them because MUST_NOT find's the exact term if the term is present in either of the inner lists then it is not deleting that document.

My Query is like this :

```
{
    "query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
        "bookList.bookId" :3163 
            }
    }
    }
}
}
```

This query is deleting only DOC2 but not DOC1.
How can i able to delete the inner list documents ?

Comment: use a wildcard query instead

Comment: wildcard query for the `book_Id` you mean? Because for book_ID's i have to use unique id's

Comment: you want to delete multiple unique bookIds at once ?

Comment: yeah i want to delete multiple bookIds

Comment: try this - https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/id=27e8129f62ec4bc59d728dabf0fd8a44&reformat=beautify_4/

Comment: Thanks @tom. But It doesn't satisfy my requirement

Comment: As per your question `I am using delete_by_query plugin in ES 2.4.0 to delete the documents that are NOT having `bookId : 3163`. What I get from this is you want to delete thse documents which do not contain `bookid:3163` in `booklist`. But Both the dicuments you mentioned contain  `bookId : 3163`. Ideally they should not be deleted

Comment: Thanks @Richa . sry i updated by question. The problem is here is Must_not finds the exact term in a documents if it exists one time too it wont delete the documents (i.e.DOC1 & DOC3) . Is there any way possible to delete those documents since they are having other bookid's . Because i even tried writing a bool query should in must_not but it too didnt work.

Comment: Must_not does not look for exact match .. term query does. In above examples you mentioned , none of the doc will get deleted as all have bookid 3163

Comment: Means you are saying even once the bookid 3163 is present in a document we cant able to delete it right?

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. Your use case seems a bit unclear. Can u tell What you want to achieve and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the filter context.

> In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated. (From: [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context))

See documentation at [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#combining-filters).

```
PUT _template/stackoverflow
{
  "template": "stackoverflow",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "bookList": {
      "properties": {
        "bookname": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "bookId": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST stackoverflow/bookList/1
{
  "bookList": [
    {
      "bookname": "HITLER",
      "bookId": 3163
    },
    {
      "bookname": "MARTIAN",
      "bookId": 1210
    }
  ]
}

POST stackoverflow/bookList/2
{
  "bookList": [
    {
      "bookname": "WASHINGTON",
      "bookId": 3163
    }
  ]
}

POST stackoverflow/bookList/3
{
  "bookList": [
    {
      "bookname": "SHELDON",
      "bookId": 3163
    },
    {
      "bookname": "MARVELS",
      "bookId": 1219
    }
  ]
}

POST stackoverflow/bookList/4
{
  "bookList": [
    {
      "bookname": "SHELDON",
      "bookId": 3164
    },
    {
      "bookname": "MARVELS",
      "bookId": 1220
    }
  ]
}
```

Execution:

```
GET stackoverflow/bookList/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "bookList.bookId": 3163
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "bookList",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "bookList": [
            {
              "bookname": "SHELDON",
              "bookId": 3164
            },
            {
              "bookname": "MARVELS",
              "bookId": 1220
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Execution:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "bookList.bookId": 3163
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "bookList",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "bookList": [
            {
              "bookname": "HITLER",
              "bookId": 3163
            },
            {
              "bookname": "MARTIAN",
              "bookId": 1210
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "bookList",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "bookList": [
            {
              "bookname": "WASHINGTON",
              "bookId": 3163
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "bookList",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "bookList": [
            {
              "bookname": "SHELDON",
              "bookId": 3163
            },
            {
              "bookname": "MARVELS",
              "bookId": 1219
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```